# Issues with Galasoft Messenger class in multi threaded environment

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, messenger

I have two classes lets say ClassA and ClassB. I have to communicate with the help of Galasoft Messenger class. In ClassA, I have the following code :-

Class A :

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotifyInterface>(this, PerformAction);

private void PerformAction(NotifyInterface objNotify)
{
   switch(objNotify.SomeProperty)
   {
    case "A":
       // Do Something
       break;
    case "B":
       // Do something else
       break;
    }
}
```

From ClassB I want to send parallel notifications with the help of Messenger i.e. I want to execute 'case A' and 'case B' parallely. I am doing something like this.

ClassB:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object context) =>
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<NotifyInterface>(objNotifyCaseA);                
        }, null);

Messenger.Default.Send<NotifyInterface>(objNotifyCaseB);
```

But the second notification is not received until the first one gets over. Is this a limitation of Messenger class that two notifications cannot be sent in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not sure whether it is a bug or by-design, but yes - messenger locks while sending messages (for instance, if you'll try to send a message from within another message's handler you'll get a dead-lock).

The issue was discussed at [mvvm light toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7581) project site and the solution was proposed as [this](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/NmsPhil/DeadlockSolved/contribution/4325#!/tab/changes) pull request, but afaik it is not yet confirmed and merged into trunk.

As a temporary workaround until a new version of toolkit is released you can get sources and apply changes mentioned above - those will solve the issue.